# Internal HDD stops working and the led indicator not flashing

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, power-supply

I have 2 HDDs, one is old and one is new. Recently my PC has a problem. HDD stops working and I sure about it because the led indicator of front panel is not flashing. I removed the old HDD and it still occurred. So I thought that my HDD is fine.

I can boot into Windows or Linux, but sometimes it stuck at booting. The screen, mouse and keyboard stop.

What happenned to my PC?? What should I check now??? The reason is my PSU or my mainboard or something else?

Update: I formatted my HDD and it still occurred.
Please help me! :(

Comment: Try making a boot USB flash stick, e.g. Linux, and boot and run from that. If that works well, then it's one or both HDD that's causing the issue. Also try a memory check (could be bad or badly-seated RAM).

Comment: There are usually tools built in to the machine you can run to test your drives for bad sectors.  I would recommend testing the disks before anything else.